# What is a more efficient way to use buffers?

Tags: buffers

Lately I've been drastically reducing the number of plugins I'm using so I'm
looking for answers using only built-in Vim features.

I've been noticing a flaw in my workflow when I'm editing a lot of buffers: I am
on a buffer and I want to switch to another one of which I don't remember the
name and which isn't the alternative buffer. So using `:b#` is not possible and
using the completion with the command `:b` isn't convenient neither.

To do that I was doing the following:

- First use `:buffers` to get the list of open buffers
- Remember the number of the buffer I want to use
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to close the list of buffers
- Use `:bX` with `X` the number of the buffer to use.

This workflow seemed pretty heavy to me so I added the following lines to my
`.vimrc`:

```
" Improve the navigation in the buffers 
nnoremap <Leader><S-b> :B<CR> 
command! B call Buffers() 

function! Buffers() 
    execute "buffers" 
    let buffer=input("Enter a buffer:") 
    execute "b" . buffer 
endfunction
```

This give me a command `:B` (and a mapping) which calls the function `:buffers` wait for an input
and finally calls `:b` followed by the input.

It works well but I'm surprised that I had to develop such a function: usually
Vim has a pretty efficient default workflow so I'm wondering if there is a
better way to switch to a buffer of which I don't know anything excepted that it
as already been opened in my editing session.

Comment: I do `:ls` followed by `:b#` (don't need to hit return or escape first, can go directly from the buffer list in 'ls'.) (Posting as comment because it doesn't seem substantial enough to be an answer? Also wondering if I'm missing something and answering the wrong question.)

Comment: @LindaJeanne: As I said `:b#` is not what I'm looking for but yeah the fact that you can save a keystroke by entering directly `:b` without pressing `enter` before is interesting. (Indeed that is maybe too light to be an answer, but it was worth a comment :-) )

Comment: I'm guessing that LindaJeanne meant the `#` character as a stand-in for a (buffer) number, rather than the literal `#` character.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I've been noticing a flaw in my workflow when I'm editing a lot of buffers: I am on a buffer and I want to switch to another one of which I don't remember the name and which isn't the alternative buffer. So using `:b#` is not possible and using the completion with the command `:b` isn't convenient neither.

On the contrary, I find tab-completion to be extremely convenient. Setting the right options to values that work for you may help a lot. These are the relevant lines from *my* `vimrc` *(they work for me but they may not work for you so don't just copy them)*:

```
nnoremap ,b :buffer *
set wildmenu
set wildignore+=*.swp,*.bak
set wildignore+=*.pyc,*.class,*.sln,*.Master,*.csproj,*.csproj.user,*.cache,*.dll,*.pdb,*.min.*
set wildignore+=*/.git/**/*,*/.hg/**/*,*/.svn/**/*
set wildignore+=*/min/*,*/vendor/*,*/node_modules/*,*/bower_components/*
set wildignore+=tags,cscope.*
set wildignore+=*.tar.*
set wildignorecase
set wildmode=full
```

With that, the right buffer is rarely more than five or six keystrokes away:

[image: tab-completion]

---

> This give me a command `:B` (and a mapping) which calls the function `:buffers` wait for an input and finally calls `:b` followed by the input.

Barry Arthur came up with a much simpler solution years ago that has become quite popular since then:

```
nnoremap <leader>b :ls<CR>:b<Space>
```

of which I proposed a slightly more versatile variant a couple years ago:

```
nnoremap gb :ls<CR>:b
```

[image: gb]

---

Since we are talking vimscript, here is a nice little function I wrote that "auto-populates" the command-line with the right command stub after list-like commands like `:ls` or `:ilist`. The advantage of that function over the mappings above is that I don't have to remember specific mappings. It works just like Vim, *but with a little twist*.

```
" smooth listing
cnoremap <expr> <CR> <SID>CCR()

function! s:CCR()
    if getcmdtype() == ":"
        let cmdline = getcmdline()
            if cmdline =~ '\v\C^(dli|il)' | return "\<CR>:" . cmdline[0] . "jump  " . split(cmdline, " ")[1] . "\<S-Left>\<Left>"
        elseif cmdline =~ '\v\C^(cli|lli)' | return "\<CR>:silent " . repeat(cmdline[0], 2) . "\<Space>"
        elseif cmdline =~ '\C^changes' | set nomore | return "\<CR>:sil se more|norm! g;\<S-Left>"
        elseif cmdline =~ '\C^ju' | set nomore | return "\<CR>:sil se more|norm! \<C-o>\<S-Left>"
        elseif cmdline =~ '\C^ol' | set nomore | return "\<CR>:sil se more|e #<"
        elseif cmdline =~ '\C^undol' | return "\<CR>:u "
        elseif cmdline =~ '\C^ls' | return "\<CR>:b"
        elseif cmdline =~ '/#$' | return "\<CR>:"
        else | return "\<CR>" | endif
    else | return "\<CR>" | endif
endfunction
```

[image: ccr]

---

That said, I'm a big proponent of "symbol-based navigation" over "file-based navigation". When applicable, symbol-based navigation is much faster and much more economic than file-based navigation.

The last GIF shows *one* mean of symbol-based navigation, by the way. The example is silly but… oh well.

Comment: I guess I haven't played enough with the `wild*` options, I will try to tweak it my way. About the Barry Arthur solution it is pretty close to @nobe4's answer that's interesting. Finally I'll have to take a deeper look to your `CCR()` function to really get it but it sees promising. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: See [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082991/vim-switching-between-files-rapidly-using-vanilla-vim-no-plugins/16084326#16084326). Specially the comic.

Comment: I'll definitely steal some of these!

Answer (score 8):

I encountered the same problem a while ago and I found a solution:

```
nnoremap <leader>b :buffers<CR>:buffer<space>
```

This will open the buffer list and *without* hiding it, give you the option to switch buffer.

I think that it makes sense that Vim does not have a "list and select" option here, these are two separate actions. But Vim is powerful enough to combine command together.

Think of it as the Unix philosophy: Do one thing and do it well.

`:buffers` lists the buffers and `:buffer xxx` allows you to select one.

Comment: That's a good way to lighten the function I suggested in my question, interesting!

Comment: If you want to make the space at the end more visible, you can do: nnoremap <leader>b :buffers<CR>:buffer<Space>|

Answer (score 1):

> For a while I used nobe4's technique like this:
>
> `nnoremap <Leader>b :set nomore<Bar>:ls<Bar>:set more<CR>:b<Space>`
>
> Then I started using Tab-completion with that (as romainl suggests)

But more recently I have found the fastest method with the **fewest keystrokes** is to use:

[`{count} CTRL-^`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#CTRL-%5E)

This is not so different from `:b#<Enter>` but as you say, you *need to know* the buffer number!

So for that I run the [MiniBufExplorer](https://github.com/fholgado/minibufexpl.vim) plugin, which displays a list of filenames across the top (like almost every other editor).  I'm sure there are numerous alternatives.

Finally, since <kbd>Ctrl-^</kbd> is a bit of a stretch for my fingers, and this is a very common operation, I moved it over to <kbd>Ctrl-E</kbd>. The [implementation for that](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/rc_files/blob/9313a52b14e02dffd264c9fad069adfdd1e94463/.vim/plugin/joeys_buffer_switcher.vim#L37:L41) is not too complex:

```
nnoremap <C-E> :<C-U>call SwitchToBuffer()<CR>

function! SwitchToBuffer()
  if v:count > 0
    exec v:count . "b"
    return
  endif

  " Whatever you want to do if you didn't provide a count
  " In this case, fall back to nobe4's technique:
  call feedkeys(":ls\n:b ")
endfunction
```

So my current buffer switching process goes something like this:

1. Look at MiniBufExplorer
2. Hit <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-E</kbd>

Sadly MBE and the script above are not Vim builtins, as you requested.  When I'm on a remote machine with no config, I just use `:b [partial]` and Tab-completion.