# navigate the buffer list

Tags: neovim, buffers

I've been looking for years for a way to quickly select a buffer from the buffer list.

scenario:

1. open the buffer list with `:ls`
2. select the desired buffer with arrows or whatever
3. open said buffer pressing enter

That would save a lot of time and keystrokes and I reckon really fits the workflow, how come it's not a default thing?
Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: There are many plugins that do that, `CtrlP`, `LeaderF`, `fzf.vim`, `vim-select` etc

Comment: `:b[uffer]` with tab-complete is frankly faster for me

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/34710/22797

Comment: (I can't find it back but I'm fairly sure we have a duplicate for this question) There are tons of plugins doing that but a nice native mapping is the following: `nnoremap gb :ls<CR>:b<space>` it lists the open buffer and starts `:b` so that you can type and get autocompletion of the buffer names.

Comment: @statox's comment provides the simplest and most "economical" answer.

Comment: @r_31415 comment reminded me of this question, after a quick search it turns out that I got this mapping [from an answer to my own question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/9161) in 2016

Answer (score 2):

I like to use the [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) plugin for that purpose.
It includes a command where you can select a buffer, and also fuzzy-search for one (as its name suggests, it fuzzy-searches using fzf).

I really love this plugin, I really use it a lot.
In fact, you can search for a lot of things with it : Lines in file, lines in buffer, Helptags, Colorschemes, Commands... and you can add other sources yourself !

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above mentioned plugins, you can also try using the buffer selector plugin:

https://github.com/yegappan/bufselect

BTW, patch 8.2.4463 added fuzzy completion for buffer names. With this
feature, you can type a few characters from the buffer name and complete
the buffer name.

Comment: ouch this plugin doesn't seem to work with neovim

Comment: If you're using neovim, you should probably look into [telescope](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim) (and maybe add the nvim tag to your question as well).

Answer (score 0):

I am using minimalist plugin `'romgrk/barbar.nvim'` . commands are listed on its [GitHub page](https://github.com/romgrk/barbar.nvim)

- You can also add your key mappings to quickly execute those commands to switch buffers/ close / prev/ next buffer

Here is snapshot of my init.lua where I configured, also if you can see on top, it shows Tab name with icon as per plugin

[image]

Comment: Welcome and thank you for writing an answer. I think your answer could be even better if you not only linked to the GitHub page but also included a short example how the plugin would be used to improve on the scenario detailed in the question.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Added snapshot

Comment: Yeah, kind of better. Prefer to post text as text, though. Sure, you can't capture the icon but the mappings should be text in a code section. Why text is better is explained in [this SO meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). The same reasons apply here as well.

Comment: @Friedrich that section is copy pasted from github link which I have already provided. you can copy text from there itself.